# URL table in the SEDE dump

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump

I have noticed a few SEDE queries that attempt to extract the referenced URLs from post bodies. Is there any chance we can get a table to list the URLs referenced by posts?

This should simplify queries and analysis involving referenced URLs.

```
URLs
  PostId
  URL
```

I thought about having the URL normalised and including a column to identify if it was referenced as a hyperlink or an embedded image, but figured that would probably require more processing than is practical.

Comment: Aside from the data processing requirements, I think this is too specialized. There is a table that tracks linked questions for the right hand side bar (not included in the data dump), but not *all* URLs in every post.